# Is "you are looking at the clock through the mirror" correct?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, sense-verbs

> Mindy: That clock on the wall is so strange!
>   Henry: What’s so strange about it?
>   Mindy: Its minute hand is moving in counterclockwise direction.
>   Henry: No, it’s moving in clockwise direction!
>   Mindy: No, it’s moving in counterclockwise direction!
>   Henry: Hey, you are looking at the clock through the mirror!

Is the last sentence in this dialogue correct? If not, what's the best way to point to Mindy on her mistake here?

Comment: I think it hardly matters. Whether *in* the mirror or *through* the mirror, virtually no listener would trip over either preposition.

Comment: Just not through the looking-glass ... I don't know what you'd find there.

Comment: Note that it's a bit unnatural to say "*in clockwise direction" etc. and it would be better just to say "clockwise" :)

Comment: @psmears - So, in a daily conversation people would say "It's moving clockwise" and "It's moving counterclockwise"? I mean, they would use it as an adverb, right?

Comment: @brilliant: Yes, that's right :)

Comment: @brilliant (Oh, and in UK English, "anticlockwise" is much more common than "counterclockwise". I think the latter is the more common in the US, but I'm not certain :)

Comment: @psmears: In American English, almost everybody says "counterclockwise".

Comment: By the way, the bit about "Its minute hand is moving" is unrealistic since it moves so slowly.  Perhaps you meant "second hand".  Also if numerals appeared on the clock face, they would be reversed in the image in the mirror.

Comment: @mgkrebbs - *Perhaps you meant "second hand" * - Yes, thanks for noticing it and telling me about it. *Also if numerals appeared on the clock face, they would be reversed in the image* - Perhaps, it was that kind of clock that doesn't have numerals, only 12 dots in their appropriate places around the clock face.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Through the mirror* is uncommon usage, apparently in both British and American English.  Typically one would use *in the mirror*, so *Oh! You're looking at the clock in the mirror.* Perhaps *Oh! You're seeing the clock through the mirror* would be be best, as *seeing... through* is a common construct (more commonly with windows).  The verb *seeing* emphasizes the perception, whereas *looking* emphasizes the directing of attention.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: physics ahead.

The common usage reflects what's actually happening to the light rays that bounce off the object.

Mirrored objects appear to be inside the mirror. Through the mirror implies the object is on the other side of the mirror and the light is passing through the mirror. Light doesn't pass through a mirror, it reflects off it.

Thus you can see something through a window. The object is actually on the other side of the window and the light passes through the glass to you.

Comment: So how would you describe Mindy's mistake here?

Comment: There are many phases that are not logically or scientifically correct, but which are still valid use. The title of Lewis Carroll's "Through the Looking Glass" indicates it's a fantasy because we all know one can't pass through a mirror. So, I'm not sure if the usage is incorrect. It's not - in my experience - a common usage. The mistake if there is one, is mixing Carroll's usage to indicate fantasy with the common usage.